# How to know a thread is in suspended state

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I am suspending a thread using an event. When the eventSuspend is signaled the thread waits on it.

```
// inside the thread function
WaitForSingleObject(eventSuspend, INFINITE );
```

Now from outside I set it to wait by `eventSuspend.ResetEvent()` but loop inside the thread function is kind of long (time consuming). How can I know that the thread has finished whatever it was doing and now it is indeed waiting on this signal?

Comment: Just use another event.

Comment: @HansPassant events are kernal objects and kind of expensive (sluggish), I was wondering if I can use the same event somehow but that doesn't make sense..does it :) oh I think might by using auto reset event

Comment: The overhead of an additional event object is negligible.

Comment: Open up Taskmanager and look at the Handle count. You should see a figure somewhere between 10k and 20k. Do you really think that **one** event object is *kind of expensive*?

Comment: @IInspectable what you say make sense. I guess the reason I was vary of it was because of the fact that MFC library is not thread safe to boost performance and I read in a multithreading book that using kernal objects are expensive (time wise).

Comment: Just to let another thread know that a specific state is reached, there is no need for an event. A simple integer or bool might be sufficient, **when you don't need to wait on it!!!**

Comment: @xMRi A simple integer or bool is not good. How will you check the state..in a loop? At least event lets you check it cleanly.

Comment: As I wrote: If you don't have to wait on it, and just want to know if a specific state is reached any variable (volatile) is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong: A thread that is waiting is not suspended!

A thread is suspended after calling `SuspendThread()` but not after calling `WaitForSingleObject()`.

Simply set a BOOL flag when the thread loop starts and reset the flag when the thread loop exits then you know if it runs or not.

If you want futher informations about a thread, like if it is supended or not, you can use the code that I posted here:
[How to get thread state (e.g. suspended), memory + CPU usage, start time, priority, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949725/how-to-get-thread-state-e-g-suspended-memory-cpu-usage-start-time-priori)